# Nestjs. Exclude from setGlobalPrefix not working

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have the following file controller

```
@Controller('uploads')
export class FileController {
  @Get(':filename')
  @Header('Content-Type', 'image')
  async getFile(@Param('filename') filename: string): Promise<StreamableFile> {
//...
```

And set the global prefix in my main.js

```
//...
  dotenv.config();

  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api', { exclude: ['uploads'] });

  app.enableCors({ origin: '*' });

  const config = new DocumentBuilder().setTitle('E-commerce Platform').build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document);
```

Yet i still have to hit /api/uploads instead of only /uploads
[image]

[image]

Comment: you could try with a shorthand option since you are applying it for all routes: `app.setGlobalPrefix('api', { exclude: ['uploads'] });`

Comment: already tried that

Comment: do you perhaps have versioning enabled as well? there was a known bug that was fixed recently - https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/11650

Comment: i did and then i removed it but the problem still persists

Answer (score 1):

You can specify route as a string (it will apply to every request method):

```
app.setGlobalPrefix('api', {exclude: ['uploads']});
```